# What's the title of the anime that has a lead character with a white long-haired man spirit with him?

Tags: story-identification, anime

My classmate and I talked about the old animes that we've watched, and we were reminiscing about the anime about a character that has a white haired man spirit. On his arm, there's something that's coming out of it. I remember that the ones that are coming out from his hand is his power. We forgot the title and the name of the lead character though.

Comment: How old is 'old' here?

Answer (score 7):

It might be **Shaman King**. The anime ran from 2001-2002, which may qualify as old.

Asakura Yoh is a Shaman who uses the spirit of Amidamaru, a long dead samurai with white hair, during the Shaman Fights.

[image: Amidamaru and Yoh]

Sometimes, mostly early in the first season, Yoh and Amidamaru combine in such a way that their power comes out of Yoh's hands.

[image: power coming from the hand]

Comment: The "thing on his arm" could also be an Oracle Bell - [here's a clear image of one of the other shamans wearing his](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v27/lunchy/Ren2_zps38b77907.jpg), and [a blurry one of Yoh with his orange Oracle Bell](http://s1.dmcdn.net/BOROS/1280x720-15o.jpg)

Comment: (The second image in the answer is actually from the episode where Yoh earns his Oracle Bell)